# exchange 2010 auto forwarders

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, forwarding

We are migrating from cpanel to exchange and have a TON of auto forwarders. is there a way to do this out of network and make a quick and easy forward rule?

For example: all emails that get sent to example@currentdomain.com forward to anyemail@anydomain.com.

I show that I can create rules but I need an actual email box of someone getting sent the email to forward it on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Exchange you typically setup a forward with a [mail enabled contact record](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124237%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx).

See: [How to forward mail to an external email address](http://exchangepedia.com/2008/02/how-to-forward-mail-to-an-external-email-address.html)

Comment: Do you guys know if there is anyway to do this beyond creating an exchange account for them using an external email? 
I'm guessing we may need to get an email program to handle the lack of flexability in exchange 2010 and handle the forwarders/auto responders.